# Jquery/PHP if statement drag and drop update array and insert into MySQL table?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

**How do I insert an if statement before my `update.php` script?** 
The if statement will verify if the jquery dropped item in list is in that lists Mysql database, and if is not it will insert it into the lists/tables database then run the `update.php`
**update.php**

```
require("db.php");

$action                 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']); 
$updateRecordsArray     = $_POST['recordsArray'];

if ($action == "updateRecordsListings"){

$listingCounter = 1;
foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {

///////currently stuck//////////
    if (???ID not present in lists database???){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO records1 SELECT * FROM records WHERE ID = (???missing array element ID???)
///////////////////////////////

        $query = "UPDATE records1 SET recordListingID = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE ID = " . $IDValue;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  
}else{
       $query = "UPDATE records1 SET recordListingID = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE recordID = " . $recordIDValue;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  
    }
```

The if statement needs to reference the $updateRecordsArray and verify the all IDs in array exist in the list MySQL table. If an item is not then insert and run the update else run update.

**unaltered working update.php**

```
 require("db.php");

$action                 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']); 
$updateRecordsArray     = $_POST['recordsArray'];

if ($action == "updateRecordsListings"){

$listingCounter = 1;
foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {

    $query = "UPDATE records1 SET recordListingID = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE recordID = " . $recordIDValue;
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
    $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($updateRecordsArray);
echo '</pre>';
echo 'If you refresh the page, you will see that records will stay just as you modified.';
}
```

Javascript:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#contentLeft ul").sortable({opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
        $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
            $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
        });                                                              
    }                                 
    });
});
```

Html:

```
    <div id="contentleft">
    <ul></UL>
    </div>

        <div id="contentRight">
      <p>Array will be displayed here.</p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have a big list in MySQL table ?

Comment: @TusharGupta A table is created for every instance and they can add as many  .sortable items as they want up to our entire list 400,000. Our default load is 50...

Comment: You have a typo in your code.  If it's there because you copied the minimal amount, I suggest you remove it, so people don't form answers regarding it.

Comment: @Daedalus I am new to coding let alone php... Which part are you talking about?

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.  It's there for a few reasons, but I would say its primary purpose(at least in actual coding applications like IDEs(integrated development environments)), is figuring out where certain elements start, and end.  In this case, you never close a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue I was having was creating an argument I had to learn **PHP** [`Operates`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) were before I could have tackled this...

```
/////////  **PLUS OR MINUS 1 /OR/ NO CHANGE**   ///////////
If ($resultCount == $numRows -1 || $resultCount == $numRows || $resultCount == $numRows + 1){
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO records1 SELECT * FROM records WHERE recordID = $recordIDValue");
    }
```

Since I will only be needing the **Current number / plus or minus 1** the only thing I needed was to get my current number of rows from the database table. Since I was already doing a query right before this I through on a `$numRows`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT recordListingID FROM records1");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The `$resultCount`statement is the other part of the if statement:

```
$updateRecordsArray     = $_POST['recordsArray'];
$ifArray = $updateRecordsArray;
$resultCount = count($ifArray);
```

I was having issues with [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) emptying `$updateRecordsArray` so I copied it with `$ifArray`  then did the [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!SELECT 1 from records WHERE ID = $IDValue)
```

the above line will tell you whether record is available in `records` table or not. then you can insert the record if this condition is met.

Comment: The first item to run in the for each statement was the if